# No data being written to S3 using Hadoop FileSystem and BouncyCastle

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bouncycastle

I'm using the following code to write encrypted data to Amazon S3:

```
byte[] bytes = compressFile(instr, CompressionAlgorithmTags.ZIP);

PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5).setWithIntegrityPacket(withIntegrityCheck).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider("BC"));

encGen.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(pubKey).setProvider("BC"));

OutputStream cOut = encGen.open(out, bytes.length);

cOut.write(bytes);
cOut.close();
```

If I set "out" to:

```
final OutputStream fsOutStr = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/hadoop/encrypted.gpg"));
```

It writes the file just fine.

However when I attempt to write it to S3, it does not give me any errors, appears to work, but there is no data on S3 when I check for it:

```
final FileSystem fileSys  = FileSystem.get(new URI(GenericUtils.getAsEncodedStringIfEmbeddedSpaces(s3OutputDir)), new Configuration());
final OutputStream fsOutStr = fileSys.create(new Path(s3OutputDir)); // outputPath on S3
```

Any idea why it writes the data perfectly fine to the local disk but does not write the file to S3?

Comment: I would guess this is just a failure to close 'fsOutStr'. Closing 'cOut' does write all remaining data to the underlying stream, but it does not close, nor even flush that stream. Presumably the S3 stream has some buffering that the FileOutputStream does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing fsOutStr solved the problem.